# Pytorch: GPU not fully utilized while training custom model on custom dataset

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to train my own model, but for some reason, my gpu is not fully utilized. Is there any way to solve this?
Here is the snipet of my Dataset.
I have already tried pin_memory=True, still not working.
environment: torch1.8 + cuda11.1 + RTX3090

```
class ImageDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self, data_path, transform=None, image_size=512):
    self.train_data_path = data_path['train']
    self.train_label_path = data_path['label']
    self.train_lables = os.listdir(self.train_label_path)
    self.train_data = os.listdir(self.train_data_path)
    self.transform = transform
    self.image_size = to_2tuple(image_size)

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.train_data)

def __getitem__(self, indx):
    if indx >= len(self.train_data):
        raise Exception("Index should be less than {}".format(len(self.train_data)))

    image = Image.open(os.path.join(self.train_data_path, self.train_data[indx]))
    final_label = Image.open(os.path.join(self.train_label_path, self.train_lables[indx]))

    image = self.transform(image)
    final_label = self.transform(final_label)

    return image, final_label
```

[image]

Comment: Is data loading taking significantly long compared to a forward pass ? If you are resizing image in your `transforms`, know that it is a costly operation and might be the bottleneck.

Comment: @harshraj22  Yes, it was. I have tried resize my dataset first in my disk, and then the situation got improved! Thanks for the tips!